# Adding custom metadata in BNMS causes counter flow error

Tags: blockchain, corda

While adding the Custom metadata in BNMS . I am getting below error.

```
 [ERROR] 2020-09-08T04:40:51,923Z [Node thread-1] transactions.TransactionBuilder. - The transaction currently built is missing an attachment for class: com/example/flows/dataClass/BNOMetadata.
                        Attempted to find a suitable attachment but could not find any in the storage.
                        Please contact the developer of the CorDapp for further instructions. {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=26210376-f913-4759-a480-bae18b2847b0, invocation_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, invocation_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, origin=O=PartyA, L=Tokyo, C=JP, session_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, session_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, thread-id=196}
[INFO ] 2020-09-08T04:40:51,923Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - Removing the pending request from the database {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=26210376-f913-4759-a480-bae18b2847b0, invocation_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, invocation_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, origin=O=PartyA, L=Tokyo, C=JP, session_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, session_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, thread-id=196}
[INFO ] 2020-09-08T04:40:51,940Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - Flow raised an error: Failed to deserialise group OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 in transaction: Internal deserialization failure: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.flows.dataClass.BNOMetadata. Sending it to flow hospital to be triaged. {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=26210376-f913-4759-a480-bae18b2847b0, invocation_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, invocation_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, origin=O=PartyA, L=Tokyo, C=JP, session_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, session_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, thread-id=196}
[INFO ] 2020-09-08T04:40:51,945Z [Node thread-1] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital. - Flow [26210376-f913-4759-a480-bae18b2847b0] admitted to hospital in state StateMachineState(checkpoint=Checkpoint(invocationContext=InvocationContext(origin=Peer(party=O=PartyA, L=Tokyo, C=JP), trace=Trace(invocationId=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, timestamp: 2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, entityType: Invocation, sessionId=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, timestamp: 2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, entityType: Session), actor=null, externalTrace=null, impersonatedActor=null), ourIdentity=O=BNO, L=Tokyo, C=JP, sessions={SessionId(toLong=-5496602332043580286)=Initiated(peerParty=O=PartyA, L=Tokyo, C=JP, peerFlowInfo=FlowInfo(flowVersion=2, appName=membership-service-2.0), receivedMessages=[], initiatedState=Live(peerSinkSessionId=SessionId(toLong=-6333690044472704062)), errors=[], deduplicationSeed=D--6333690044472704062-3691563152744622828)}, subFlowStack=[Inlined(flowClass=class com.r3.businessnetworks.membership.flows.bno.RequestMembershipFlowResponder, subFlowVersion=CorDappFlow(platformVersion=7, corDappName=membership-service-2.0, corDappHash=8FF7CE72627FDF7EA750D1DE22C0328AEB363E17E0169A6938DA9C5F93AB923E), isEnabledTimedFlow=false)], flowState=Started(flowIORequest=Receive(sessions=[FlowSessionImpl(destination=O=PartyA, L=Tokyo, C=JP, sourceSessionId=SessionId(toLong=-5496602332043580286))]), frozenFiber=45711FFA01B46307ED47F4A051647F0B522694853E5040F182D98E726D273472), errorState=Clean, numberOfSuspends=1), flowLogic=com.r3.businessnetworks.membership.flows.bno.RequestMembershipFlowResponder@41bb1134, pendingDeduplicationHandlers=[], isFlowResumed=true, isWaitingForFuture=false, future=null, isAnyCheckpointPersisted=true, isStartIdempotent=false, isRemoved=false, isKilled=false, senderUUID=2f6073b4-c826-4869-a739-27594e558f4b) {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=26210376-f913-4759-a480-bae18b2847b0, invocation_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, invocation_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, origin=O=PartyA, L=Tokyo, C=JP, session_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, session_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, thread-id=196}
[INFO ] 2020-09-08T04:40:51,948Z [Node thread-1] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital. - Error 1 of 1: {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=26210376-f913-4759-a480-bae18b2847b0, invocation_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, invocation_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, origin=O=PartyA, L=Tokyo, C=JP, session_id=9341077f-7c5f-4852-9c68-3897fc5025be, session_timestamp=2020-09-08T04:40:50.395Z, thread-id=196}
net.corda.core.internal.TransactionDeserialisationException: Failed to deserialise group OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 in transaction: Internal deserialization failure: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.flows.dataClass.BNOMetadata
    at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt:87) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.TransactionUtilsKt$deserialiseComponentGroup$1.invoke(TransactionUtils.kt) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.LazyMappedList.get(InternalUtils.kt:597) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:581) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
```

Comment: Always supply the error log entries in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom metadata ,that is  metadata class should belong to the contracts module of our Cordapp

Answer (score 0):

You have a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.flows.dataClass.BNOMetadata` error, which means that the node that's running your flow doesn't have that class on its classpath, that can be solved in one of 2 ways:

1. If the missing class is a state, contract, or flow; you need to install the CorDapp that contains that class on the node, meaning you need to place the jar file of that CorDapp inside the `cordapps` folder of the node.
2. If the missing class is not part of a CorDapp (e.g. some utils class that you created); you can modify the `node.conf` of your node and add a `jarDirs` entry (see documentation [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/corda-configuration-fields.html#jardirs)). You can create a folder inside your node (call it `libs`) then set `jarDirs = [ ${baseDirectory}"/libs" ]` and place the jar file that contains your class inside. When the node starts it will add any class that it finds inside the `jarDirs` directory to its classpath.

Comment: Thanks!!my data class is placed in workflows folder.So that wont be in cordapp jar?

Comment: Yes, you have to place the jar file of the workflows CorDapp inside the `cordapps` folder of your node, then restart the node; once you restart the node, the flow hospital will attempt replaying your flow from the last checkpoint.

Comment: Well the error clearly says that the class is not found; so I would suggest that you go to that jar file and open it (double click on it) and explore the path leading to the missing class to make sure that `BNOMetadata` class exists in that jar file or not.

Comment: Thanks!! I verified.The `.class` file is generated for `BNOMetadata`

Comment: I wonder if adding the `@CordaSerializable` annotation to that class solves the problem, can you try that? Add the annotation, rebuild the module, place the new jar file in the `cordapps` folder, restart the node, check whether the log file is still producing the same error message.

Comment: Sorry Sil, I'm out of ideas; post a link to your question on Corda's Slack channel so others can see it and contribute.

Comment: That's perfectly alright..Thanks for your great support and fast reply!!Have a good day